# why the count of each task's parameters should be the same in async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Sorry for bad question name since I don't know how to describe it clearly.

I just met a problem when I use the [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) and fix it at last.
But I still don't know what happens behind it.

**What I have found:**
When we use *async.waterfall*, the ***parameter counts*** of last task should be the same as next task.
Otherwise, it will say `"undefined is not a function"`.

I've tried some tests, and I also try to figure out its [source code](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/dist/async.js#L679).
Sorry, I'm a newbie in JavaScript. I couldn't understand lots of javascript pattern. It's too hard for me.

After struggling with source code for more than two hours, I need some help.
Could you give me some tips about these two questions:

> 1. how does it process the **error**, in which kind of situation, it will jump to last callback?

According to my test result, `'', null,undefined` won't cause the jump. This behavior makes sense to me.

> 2. why the count of parameters should be the same exactly?

If pass only one argument in last task, of course, the callback will be undefined. But I'd like to know much behind it.

I can know these words: apply, closure, etc when they're separated in simple demos. But when they're joined together, I become blind.

Both short answer and long answer are very appreciated.
If possible, maybe can provide some links and I can study it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Code Sample:

```
var async = require('async');

function test_waterfall() {
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {

      /* works - pass all */
      // callback(null, '1')           // null 12
      // callback('','first')          // null 12
      // callback(undefined,'1')       // null 12



      /* skip second, jump to error*/
      // callback('error1')             // error1  undefined
      // callback('erro1', 'value1')    // error1  value1
      // callback({})                   // {}  undefined
      // callback([])                   // []  undefined

      /* wrong -- undefined is not a function*/
      callback()
        // callback('')
        // callback(undefined)
        // callback(null)
    },
    function(arg, callback) {
        // If pass only one argument in last task, 
        //of course, the callback will be undefined.
      callback(null, arg+'2');
    }
  ], function(err, result) {
    console.info(err)
    console.info(result)
  });
}

test_waterfall()
```

Comment: Your first question has to do with [falsey and truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) in javascript. `null, undefined, ''` get evaluated to `false` so not considered errors by async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters should match because that's how it is implemented and the description of the api says: https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

The reason why you get `undefined is not a function` if you don't pass the same amount of arguments is because:

1. `waterfall` passes to the next `task/function` the `results/parameters` returned in callback `+ extra param as a callback` function. So:
2. If let's say your first `task1` returns `callback(null, 1, 2);` then next `task/function` which you passed to `waterfall` is called by internals like this `task2(1, 2, callback)` but because you defined your `task2`  with different amount of params like `function(param1, callback){}` actually to `callback` param it passes 2 not a `callback` function.  so you think its `callback` function but you call something like 2(null, param) and get an error lets say `number is not a function`. If you pass less (not more) parameters in your `task1` function then in your `task2` `callback` parameter is `undefined` rather than an actual callback you expect.

You can get passed parameters as `arguments` object. so if you `task1` calls `callback(null, 'a', 'b')`, then inside `callback` `arguments[0]` is error param (`null`), `argument[1] == 1` and `argument[2] == 'b'`. then they call your `task2(argument[1], argument[2], callbackFn)` and the behaviour continuos as waterfall till the last function. About arguments you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Hi, @jonasnas   these behaviors you mentioned make sense to me. I've already test them when I post this issue, and yes, you're right. 
Would you understand how is it implemented?  Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: Yes, you can get passed parameters as 'arguments' object. so if you call task1 calls callback(null, 'a', 'b'), arguments[0] is error param, argument[1] == 1 and argument[2] == 'b'. then they call you task2(argument[1], argument[2], callbackFn)